# Show Loader indicator for every HTTP request and hide views until completed Using HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, http

I am new in angular2.

Please give tutorial to show loader indicator for every http request step by step, and hide view after data loaded until setTime of loader indicator is completed  , using HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

This topic is explained very well here 
https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/show-loader-on-every-request-in-angular-2-9a0fca86afef